# twitter timeline streaming with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

i want to stream my own twitter timeline with python and tweepy and use code in below but it just print me some numbers and i dosent print my timeline twitts. Can you help me?

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

consumer_key = 'abc'
consumer_secret = 'abc'
access_token = 'abc'
access_secret = 'abc'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print (data)
        return True
    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener()) 
twitterStream.userstream(encoding='utf8')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a [look at the documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html) it says:

> The `on_data` method of Tweepy’s StreamListener conveniently passes data from statuses to the `on_status` method.

The numbers you are seeing are the object IDs of the Tweets.  You will need to do something like:

```
def on_status(self, status):
    print(status.text)
```